# Why set user.name to an empty string? (Hartl rails book)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = " "
    assert_not @user.valid?
    end
```

I'm not really getting this test, particularly line 2. I assume to assert_not @user.valid? is just the same as assert !@user.valid? but I guess he thought the former was easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that for this test you also have a presence validation ( `presence: true`) in your user model, for both the email and name of the user. That is why `@user.email = " "` is set to an empty string; Based on the validation presence conditions, the user is now invalid. Side note: what this is actually doing is calling the blank method.

And yes, you're right, `assert_not @user.valid?` or `assert !@user.valid?` will return the same thing. What this line means is that `assert_not @user.valid?` passes if the object is false, namely, if the user is invalid.

So basically, what it says is that "ok, because this guy has a blank(invalid) email, we're testing to make sure that he should also be an invalid user". So the purpose of the test is to ensure that any user with a blank email is not a valid user.

Answer (score 0):

The email is set to an "empty" string in order to make the `@user` object invalid and therefore make the test pass.

I am, of course, assuming that the `email` attribute is a required field of `User`. With this assumption, the test would FAIL if the `user` was still valid even when the email address was empty.

Comment: but even if there was no name wouldn't you get the same result? So what's the purpose of the test?

Comment: I'm assuming that the `@user` object is a valid object, meaning, its name has either been already assigned in the `@user` variable, or the user's name is not a required field. Your 4 lines of code leave a lot to be assumed.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this test is to make sure that a user object of the  `User` model is invalid unless it has `email` attribute set.

To do this, we are deliberately setting `email` attribute of `@user` instance variable to `"  "`, or blank, thereby making `@user` invalid.
Now `@user.valid?` returns false since you have the following line in `user.rb` file:

```
validates :email, presence: true
```

You are definitely right in saying that `assert !@user.valid?` is the same as `assert_not @user.valid?`. You can use both to test the same behaviour.